# Script Embedded SQLite With TCL

Tags: c++, sqlite, tcl

I am writing a C++ application that embeds TCL and for its database operations I am also embedding SQLite in it. I would like to be able to do the following:

1. Write TCL scripts for the embedded SQLite from the embedded TCL interpeter.
2. Pass an SQLite connection from the embedded TCL interpreter to C++ and use it in C++ for db operations, as well as the other way around.

I would appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Do people still use TCL? Also, the question is way to broad. It's effectively your wish list only.

Comment: SQLite's own test suite is partly written in Tcl.  See http://wiki.tcl.tk/2633 for some info on Tcl/SQLite integration.

Comment: Thanks @Colin, but I couldn't find any info on the page that could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl 8.6 should ship with a build of the SQLite interface, the `sqlite3` package. However, there's no (official) way to share a database connection from the package with your C++ code; there's simply no API in the package that you can call from C++ to get the connection. **The official workaround is to create another connection from your C++ code** and that shouldn't be too onerous unless you're doing weird mixing of things between queries in the two language bindings, a very much *not* normal use case.

You can hack it by using `Tcl_GetCommandInfo()` to retrieve, among other things, the Tcl database handle command's `ClientData` field. That can then be cast to a pointer to a structure whose first field is a `sqlite3*` handle, much as you'd obtain with `sqlite3_open()`. Which is *messy* and *fragile*. Also, you'd still need to respect the usual rules, such as needing to keep to a single thread. This really isn't what I'd recommend!

Comment: many thanks for your answer. Since I want to embed TCL, my intent is to include only the TCL core code and SQLite code in my project and build then into one exec file. This way I can use SQLite in my C++ code as well as in TCL. Is  this achievable?